# Ошибка при определении функции: error C2572: redefinition of default parameter

Tags: c++

> Ошибка: error C2572: 'foo' : redefinition of default parameter : parameter 1

Мне необходимо сначала объявить функцию, а затем определить её. При этом необходимо задать один параметр как параметр по умолчанию. Но не получается. Почему?

```
void foo(int i = 1); //объявляем функцию

void foo(int i = 1) //тут нужно определить
{

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вы, как правильно написано в сообщении об ошибке, дважды определили значение параметра по умолчанию. Можно только один раз.

Уберите значение по умолчанию из имплементации, всё будет работать как надо.

Comment: Спасибо, так компилируется

Comment: пожалуйста!